# pytest.mark.paramterize doesnot accept new changed value of global variable

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

In the following code, the test script failed because of empty paramters in list1 even if it is changed in test_1 test function.

```
import pytest,csv
list1 = []

def test_1():
    global list1
    print "IN TEST1"
    list1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]



@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input", list1)
def test_eval(test_input):
    print list1
    print "PARAMTERIZE FUNCTION"
    print (test_input)
```

How do i access new value of list1 in pytest.parametrize ?

Comment: at where you are calling `test_1`? I cant see call to this function.

Comment: pytest automatically executed functions which have "test_" prefix,so test_1 is executed first and then test_eval.And the value of list1 is changed in the test_1 by global parameter,but it is not changed in test_eval functions

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not calling the function, so `list1` is not updated. Either call the function `test_1()` before the test or a better way is given below:

```
def test_1():
    print "IN TEST1"
    list1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
    return list1

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input", test_1())
def test_eval(test_input):
    print "PARAMTERIZE FUNCTION"
    print (test_input)
```